# Git clone through a proxy without changing http.proxy setting

Tags: git, github, proxy, settings

Is there a way to go though clone through a proxy without changing the Git settings.
I often want to clone a repository on GitHub at work, where we have a proxy, but if I remember correctly, setting a proxy causes issues when you try to clone without the proxy being there (for instance we have an internal repository that I don't go through the proxy for). It has been awhile since I tried changing the setting and had issues when not using the proxy, so please let me know if that issue has been fixed.

Example of issue in case I wasn't as clear as I'd like to be:

No proxy set:

- Can get internal repo
- Can't get to GitHub

Proxy set:

- Can't get internal repo
- Can get GitHub

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY system variables on Windows (and according vars on Linux) and everything works well.